# I want to create transformation in which I want to add multiple inputs table column value into one table in the same column in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I want to create transformation in which I want to add multiple inputs table column value into one table in the same column in pentaho
e.g Two input products table having id and name and one output table with id and column wants to add all values of both in output table

[Table one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeEH3.png)
[Table two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y50tn.png) 
I want to in one table and the same column

Comment: Show sample data and desired results.

Comment: @underscore_d check now

Answer (score 2):

Just draw arrows from the table one and two to the same process step.

Ah, yes, PDI will tell you the input flow must have the same metadata, meaning the columns must be in the same order, with the same name and the same type. So, in your case you'll need to rename the columns with a `Select Value`.

[image: Like this]: